# Hide element with same text on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide any text on the page that appears inside a div (with a specific class) more than once. For example, if my page has:

```
<div class="year"><h3>2015</h3></div>
<div class="year"><h3>2016</h3></div>
<div class="year"><h3>2016</h3></div>
<div class="year"><h3>2016</h3></div>
<div class="year"><h3>2017</h3></div>
```

In this example, I want to use jQuery to check if there is more than one div (with the class of "year") that has the same child h3 text. If so, then hide all except the first, resulting in this:

```
<div class="year"><h3>2015</h3></div>
<div class="year"><h3>2016</h3></div>
<div class="year"></div>
<div class="year"></div>
<div class="year"><h3>2017</h3></div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: And what have **you** tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: This is about as far as I've got: https://jsfiddle.net/6jjt4yeo/

Comment: Here is some documentation for you to read.. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend doing is grabbing all of the elements with `$('.year')`, and then setting up an array to store the `.innerHTML` of each element. You can then loop over the elements, and check if their `.innerHTML` is in this array. If it's not, it gets added to the array. If it already exists, hide the element:

```js
var elements = $('.year');
var existing_content = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (existing_content.indexOf(elements[i].innerHTML) === -1) {
    existing_content.push(elements[i].innerHTML);
  }
  else {
    $(elements[i]).hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="year"><h3>2015</h3></div>
<div class="year"><h3>2016</h3></div>
<div class="year"><h3>2016</h3></div>
<div class="year"><h3>2016</h3></div>
<div class="year"><h3>2017</h3></div>
```

Note that this assumes that the `.year` elements all have identical content. If only **part** of the `.year` content is the same, you will need to update the `elements` selector to be more specific, and target the elements with identical content directly.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I can't get it to work properly with my code, here's what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/v6pqsunq/  ... For some reason it's still showing "1995" numerous times instead of once

Comment: That's because your `.innerHTML` is different for each element. In your question, you showed identical `.innerHTML` content. In your fiddle, you need to replace `var elements = $('.year');` with `var elements = $('.year > h3 > a');` -- https://jsfiddle.net/yqsz9g81/

Comment: Oh thats my bad, sorry about that. It worked perfectly, thanks so much!

Comment: No problem :) I've just updated my answer to also cover this constraint :)